# jQuery replaceWith not working properly. So lost

Tags: javascript, string

I'm having difficulties changing an error message in this app using Spring.

If the user enters in the wrong account a custom message (that I can't edit) fires.
I need to replace `[BR][BR]` (coming from netBiscuits) with an empty `string('');`

The error message is from a message.properties file if I need to I will post that as well.

Here's my code:

```
var text = "[BR]''[BR]";
var data = st(text);
replace(data);

function st(ip) 
{
    var str = ip;
    return str.replaceWith(/[.*?]/g,"");
}
```

This is not my original code, but the `replace(data)` is a spin-off a test I was running with an alert box because after about 8 hours, I'm still stuck.

Comment: `text` is a string. [`replaceWith`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) is a jQuery method, not a string method.

Answer (score 2):

For strings, use the standard [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function :

```
 return str.replace(/[.*?]/g,"");
```

[JQuerys replaceWith](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) is used to replace elements.

But, even if I'm not sure of your exact goal, I think your regex doesn't do what you want.

You probably should escape the `[` and `]` :

```
return str.replace(/\[.*?\]/g,"");
```

Comment: Thanks dystroy! Ok so before we go further with this I actually replaced the code and put it  back into an alert box to show     var text = ('[BR][BR]','');
var data = st(text);
alert(data);

function st(ip) {
  var str = ip;
  return str.replace(/[](.*)>/g,'');
}            ...this is giving me a better result by taking out the biscuits tags in the alertbox. Now how do I remove it from my jsp?